# Random salt encryption / decryption

Tags: encryption, cryptography, salt

I am trying to encrypt third party passwords and decrypt when I needed. I wonder if there are any standard solution to mix password with a random salt for each password independently similarly how BCrypt does it?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Do you just want to hash for verification or do you actually want to encrypt / decrypt the password? Do you know about the IT security site of stack exchange? Isn't bcrypt sufficiently standardized?

Comment: @WildGoat: This sounds like a question about "password hashing", not "encryption".  [The difference isn't subtle](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).

Comment: The equivalent of a _salt for hashing_ is the initialization vector _IV for encryption_. Hasing is one way, encryption is two way, so they are used in different situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is PBKDF2 which is the password based key derivation function used in the Password Based Encryption (PBE) standards, also known as PKCS#5 and standardized in [RFC 2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898#section-5.2). Both Java and .NET contain implementations of this scheme out of the box.

Comment: There are [sane .NET BCrypt implementations](https://paragonie.com/blog/2016/02/how-safely-store-password-in-2016#csharp) available too.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, I am basically looking for good way protect against rainbow tables and bruteforce. Do you think PBKDF2 is good enough for that?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes, seems that PBKD2 is a one way hash function, what I need is the way to encrypt and decrypt passwords having some including some random salt. Or do you think including user name together with constant key is sufficient enough?

Comment: A salt is specific for key derivation, not encryption. Both bcrypt and PBKDF2 are *password based* key derivation functions. In that sense this answer *directly* provides a solution for the problem stated in the question ("...standard solution to mix password with a random salt for each password independently similarly how BCrypt does it"). What is "sufficient enough" depends on your use case and threat model, neither of which is described well (hence the comment below your question).

Comment: If you mean, mix a *master* password with salt to encrypt each third-party password, that is exactly what PBKDF2 gives you. And then, it can certainly be sufficient against rainbow tables and brute force. Because, the attacker is after the encrypted password. But that is encrypted by a unique, one-time key based on the master password. As strong as that key is, the encrypted password is safe. For example, a 128-bit key with an AES cipher using random IV is completely sufficient, given a good master password, good random salt, and a large iteration count for the PBKDF2.